# How to plot a "grouped scatterplot" with non-categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am a bit confused how to use `seaborn.stripplot()` to plot multiple columns of data points when these data do not have "categorical" labels.

For example, users can plot "grouped" scatterplots as follows, with the `tips` dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")   # internal dataset

print(tips)

     total_bill   tip     sex smoker   day    time  size
0         16.99  1.01  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     2
1         10.34  1.66    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     3
2         21.01  3.50    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     3
3         23.68  3.31    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     2
4         24.59  3.61  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     4
5         25.29  4.71    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     4
....      .....      .....      .....
```

There are measurements grouped together by the category `day`, whereby we produce scatterplots as follows:

```
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
```

[image]

Now, I would like to re-produce this "grouped scatterplot format" plot with non-categorical data, with data in each column:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")

df

      total_bill_A   total_bill_B    total_bill_C   total_bill_D      
0     16.99          21.01           15.99          14.50  
1     10.34          21.66           12.99          16.50  
2     21.01          23.50           7.25           17.50   
3     23.68          23.31           9.99           12.50 
4     24.59          23.61           10.00          15.50  
5     25.29          24.71           11.00          19.50   
....               ....
```

The y-axis here is `price`, and the x axis should be each of these columns, `total_bill_A`, `total_bill_B`, `total_bill_C`, and `total_bill_D`, similar to the above for Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday.

How could I plot something like these `seaborn`? Is it possible to do this with `seaborn.stripplot()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) the dataframe and name the parameters accordingly to apply to the `stripplot` as follows:

```
df_strip = pd.melt(df, var_name='total_bill', value_name='price')
sns.stripplot(x="total_bill", y="price", data=df_strip)
```

[image]